# BaseModelFormSet "metaclass conflict"

Tags: python, django, forms, method-resolution-order

While following [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)

I end up with this error :

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Only thing I change is passing an argument to filter the queryset. The doc shows an easier case.

forms.py :

```
class BaseEducationFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.pop('curriculum_fk')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Education.objects.filter(curriculum__id=id)
```

views.py :

```
def cv_edit(request, pk):
    EducationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Education, fields = ('title', 'institution', 'place') , formset=BaseEducationFormSet(curriculum_fk=pk))
```

I though that "modelformset_factory" would handle this job...

Comment: The error is (probably) not located there. Typically such error occurs on a place where you have *multiple* inheritance, or inheritance with an extra metaclass.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the answer to my question is to use a "BaseInlineFormSet" object and his own factory.

This is described later in the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet)